# Diffie-Hellman Assumption

Tags: diffie-hellman

I'm wondering if the following problem is as hard as computational or decision Diffie-Hellman problem? (Or is it actually an easy problem because $c$ is available?)

Given a cyclic group $G$ and let its order be $q$.
Given $g$, $q$, $g^a$ and $g^b$ and $c \in Z_q$, decide if $c \equiv a*b \mod q$.

Another version of the problem could be: let $G$ be a group of unknown order (e.g., where RSA or strong RSA assumption could apply, thus computing roots would be hard).

Comment: I assume we are given $g$ and $q$.

Comment: This problem is obviously no harder than DDH (given an Oracle that can solve DDH, it's easy to solve your problem)

Comment: Yes, given g and q. I have rephrased question correspondingly. Thanks!